# Loop with matrices created with assign function in R project

Tags: string, r, loops, matrix, assign

I created several matrices with the assign function as follows:

```
for (i in 2:105) { # Loop for creating and filling matrices
    (assign(paste("m",i,sep=""),Datos[(x[i-1]+1):x[i],1:14]))  
}
```

This give me several matrices... from `m2` to `m105`... which is exactly what i wanted because `i` can extract and call this matrices with their index like `m2[i,j]` or `m65[i,j]` etc.

My problem is that I want to make a loop which include all my "m" matrices, but I don't know what could be the right code to do so because I need something like:

`paste("m",i,"[i,j]",sep="")` to return `m2[i,j]`...`m3[i,j]` ...... `m105[i,j]` and do the loop over this , but clearly the paste function returns a string and don't recognize `m2`.... `m105` like matrices..... it returns `m2[i,j]` as text.

What should I do ?

Thank you very much ! 
regards

Comment: This is the wrong way to approach this problem.Making a list would result in much less tortured code.

Comment: I tried to use a list and was successful in generating my matrices. for example if "l" was my list variable l[[2]] to l[[105]] returned all my matrices.... the thing is that I didn't know how to access to specific indexes of every matrix in the list... something like extract l[[2]][i,j]...still help on this would be appreciated... Thanks a lot !

Comment: I finally understood how to manage a list. I did:                
  ` v<-vector("list",104)
for (i in 2:105) { # Loop for creating and filling matrices
v[[i]]<-Datos[(x[i-1]+1):x[i],1:14]
}` And now I can call my matrices with their indexes easily as `v[[i]][k,j]`..... thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `get`:

```
get(paste("m", i, sep=""))[i,j]
```